# Migrate different Virtual machines and sql vm to different tenant in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-migrate

I want to migrate different virtual machines running in Azure from tenant A to Tenant B .
Could someone guide me the links and mandatory things that to do ?

Our company is going to merge with another company in this case we want to migrate our workloads from one tenant in azure to another tenant , all workloads are windows virtual machine  , could someone guide me any use links or issues we will face ?

Comment: To migrate virtual machines from one tenant to another in Azure, you can use the Azure Site Recovery Deployment Planner. This tool can help you discover and assess machines that can be moved to Azure, recommend the type of VM to run, and estimate the cost of the workload. You can also work with an Azure migration partner for large migrations where you need to move hundreds or more VMs. For more information on migrating workloads to Azure, you can refer to the following resources shared below

Comment: -   [Migrate your e-commerce solution to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/industries/retail/migrate-ecommerce-solution#rehost)
-   [Microsoft 365 tenant-to-tenant migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-tenant-to-tenant-migrations?view=o365-worldwide#microsoft-365-tenant-to-tenant-migrations)

Comment: Detailed steps are provided [here](https://darawtechie.com/2021/07/19/move-an-azure-vm-to-another-tenant/)

- [Similar Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/258686/how-to-migrate-azure-vm-from-one-tenant-to-another)